# Android emulator won't boot

Tags: android, eclipse

When trying to run an android emulator (either from eclipse or the cmd line) it simply starts an empty black box with the title 0: (obviously replacing  with the name of the avd!).  It never boots - doesn't even get to the boot animation.

Logcat shows absolutely no output and devices shows it as emulator:5554 - offline

This happens regardlessof which avd I start - and they had all previously worked.

I'm running all this on linux.

Edit: interestingly it also now fails to recognise an actual phone plugged in with debugging enabled... Android dev is now effectively impossible on this machine until I fix this...

Edit #2: If I create a new emulator and/or edit an existing one (even if I don't actually change anything) enables it to boot.  This obviously enables me to move forward, but there is clearly still a problem with adb (actual devices still won't connect) which I still need to fix.

Edit #3: Scratch that last edit - it seemed to work briefly, but not anymore...

Comment: How are you running your emulator?

Comment: try installing Eclipse upgrade on linux machine

Comment: If this above solutions doesn't solve your problem,then go on to create a newer Emulator and try to Start that.

Comment: I've tried restarting eclipse & upgrading the software - no dice.  I've tried running the emulator both from eclipse and fro mthe cmd line - no difference

Answer (score 2):

The emulator is a horribly slow piece of junk. Startup times of ten minutes or more are not unheard of. You are better off connecting an actual Android device via USB. If you insist on using the emulator, keep it running between debugging sessions to preserve its state (and your sanity).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Do adb reset in eclipse ddms devices view
```

and go to adb try this

```
   adb shell stop
   adb shell start
```

Comment: restart adb by using adb kill-server and adb start-server then check adb devices

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem in Eclipse--was getting errors in my XML files--as a result my R variable was unable to resolve.  When the new Android Application project is created, another appcompat_v7 project is also created.  These two projects are associated.  The problem cropped up when I kept my main project open, but closed my appcompat_v7 project.  When both were open at the same time, the problem disappeared.

Simple, but there it is.